# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 4), indices imply (1, 4)

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone explain to me what is the cause of this error?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
                 [11, 2, 5, 3],
                 [4, 35, 7, 36],
                 [4, 5, 17, 16],
                 [14, 5, 37, 6]
                  ],
    index=["col1"],             
    columns=["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the `index=['col1']` argument. The data you're passing to `pd.DataFrame()` is a list of 4 lists, where each list has 4 items, so there will be 4 rows and 4 columns.

But, you're setting the index (row labels) to be only 1 item, when there are going to be 4 items. You need to either reduce the data to 1 row, or add 3 more items to your `index=['col1']` list:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
                 [11, 2, 5, 3],
                 [4, 35, 7, 36],
                 [4, 5, 17, 16],
                 [14, 5, 37, 6]
                  ],
    index=["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"], # <--- more items added
    columns=["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      col1  col2  col3  col4
col1    11     2     5     3
col2     4    35     7    36
col3     4     5    17    16
col4    14     5    37     6
```

Comment: first of all, thanks for providing the answer! I have a question. When I set column A for index, I mean 4 values of this column as an index, I mean, each value of column A as an index for each row. Is it wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, @Sarah. Yes, you can set any column to be the index, which would make each value of that column the label for the row that value is on. Use `set_index` for that, e.g. `df = df.set_index('col3')` to make `col3` the index.